# Question dump for The Art of Electronics 3rd Edition

Tags: discussion

I just bought the [Art of Electronics 3rd Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521377099). I know close to 0 about EE, but I'm eager to learn. I spent like $150 American pesos on this paper weight to get a Cambridge-esque education and it doesn't have the answers to the exercises! Even worse, [the Student Manual isn't even out yet!](http://artofelectronics.net/student-manual/)

Would it be appropriate to ask all of the questions individually and index them on EE? I'd be willing

- Ask the questions
- Mark them up and tag them properly
- Answer them to the best of my ability

Would this kind of MASSIVE Q/A submission be welcome? This book is like 150 million pages but these questions will at least provide a helpful guide to anyone who can't afford the student guide, and being that it's not out yet -- it seems that it'd be *highly* relevant now.

Comment: No, and I'll elaborate in a bit.

Answer (score 15):

No, a question dump of any sort would not be welcome. I have several reasons, which I will try to articulate.

Even a few questions a day is a significant number for our site. This isn't Stack Overflow, we can't sweep new questions off the front page in minutes. This will drown out people who have real questions, and needlessly annoy our user base. These aren't "questions based on actual problems you face", these are just problems.

Also, a massive upload of questions from the book almost certainly constitutes a copyright violation. This would exceed any fair use allowance.

The lack of availability for the student manual is unfortunate, but only temporary. From your link, the manual will be published in the fourth quarter of 2015, which starts in just over a month from now. While you may argue that it's relevant now, by that logic it will be irrelevant in a month or two.

In conclusion, we are not interested in developing a student manual for your textbook.

Comment: It'll never be irrelevant to people who can't afford the student manual, but shouldn't be there be a better way to not-clog up the front page than to simply abstain from adding questions and answers that are likely to be useful to others?

Comment: @EvanCarroll Well if someone has a question and cannot solve a problem from the book and can't afford the student manual, he is still welcome to ask it in a normal way. So in the end the relevant questions are here and the unrelevant won't annoy other people?

Comment: @EvanCarroll A Q/A page for the book could certainly be valuable (if possibly illegal), but Stack Exchange is the wrong place to host it. Something like Wikia would be a better choice.